# zfs one pool error

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, zfs

I have zpool with name zroot
and zroot has 4 pool
when electricity down system reboots and than i saw some error with 1 pool:

```
Solaris: Warning: can`t open object for zroot/var/crash
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
Solaris: Warning: can`t open object for zroot/var/crash
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
log_sysevent: type19 is not emplement
```

System FreeBSD 8.2, zfs v28
How i can destroy zroot/var/crash with out default tool zfs/zroot because it`s not work, just freeze.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this a year or two ago, where every time I used the zfs/zpool tool, the system hung.

I can't remember what the issues was but it happened during a 8.X OS upgrade. I was able to work around it by installing FreeBSD on a USB drive, booted from that, and then did a 'zpool import'.

Try booting onto a new 9.1 disk and see if you can perform a zpool import. If so, then use the zfs tools to destroy and recreate that file system. If you don't have a spare thumb drive or CD, you can try booting single user, moving the ZFS cache (/boot/zfs/zpool.cache) out of the way, and then attempting to start up zfs manually (/etc/rc.d/hostid and /etc/rc.d/zfs) and see how far you can get.

Answer (score 0):

From FreeBSD site: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/filesystems-zfs.html

```
zfs destroy zroot/var/crash
```

Comment: i wrote default tools zfs|zpool didn`t work with my pool`s. I need to do it something else :(

Comment: If the tools for it do not work, then you will need to boot from CD and try to make a force import on it.
zpool import -F zroot
if it does not help, then in that case you might have to recreate your zpool. In this case a backup will be important.

Comment: does recreate pool save information inside pools? and recreate mean destroy and create? because destroy not work... And ofcause i do all of it from another system(boot from flash with freebsd)

Comment: recreate does mean destroy and create. Doing this will destroy completely the data inside your pools. So you should make backup of what you can.

If even by booting from a cd/flash drive you are not able to destroy the pool then your next step should be to wipe out the partition table and recreate a new one. 
After this, create the pool again and recover the data that was previously backed up.

Comment: **CAREFUL!** `zpool import -F` is **potentially destructive.** It is not at all the same thing as `zpool import -f` (which *shouldn't* be needed, either).